# Google Sheets cannot read range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Made a spreadsheet that has inputs in GBP and EUR, made a script that would adjust the number format to GBP or EUR depending on another cell. I would edit the cell to be 'UK' or 'IE' and then it would adjust the total 4 cells to the right. There error I now get is

> 'Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")'

I added a new sheet containing some other information but then deleted it, thinking this was an issue. It was working originally but now seems to not work despite no changes (made 3 days ago)

```
  if (e.range.getColumn() == '1') {
    switch (e.value) {
      case 'UK':
        e.range.offset(0,4).setNumberFormat('[$£-809]#,##0.00'); 
        break;
      case 'IE':
        e.range.offset(0,4).setNumberFormat('[$€]#,##0.00');  
        break;
      default:
        e.range.offset(0,4).setNumberFormat('[$£-809]#,##0.00'); 
    }
  }
}
```

When I change column 1 to be 'UK' or 'IE' it should change the number format 4 cells to the right to be in GBP or EUR

Comment: Show the full script, this is just a snippet and we can't see if you're using event objects correctly (which is likely the issue here).

Comment: On what trigger is this script being executed?

Comment: Most likely your missing your [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)